# Git didn't add x64\SQLite.Interop.dll

Tags: wpf, git, sqlite

I installed SQLite into my WPF project via Nuget. Then added the entire project to a remote repo. Then I cloned the project on another machine, and had a broken build.

```
x64\SQLite.Interop.dll was missing.
```

I'm puzzled why Git didn't include one file from my project. I checked the repo on BitBucket and confirmed it is not there. Git status reports `nothing to commit, working directory clean`

It added the x86 version, but not the x64 version, I can't imagine why.

```
    (project)\x64\SQLite.Interop.dll      Git ignored this file!

    (project)\x86\SQLite.Interop.dll
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might want to check the `.gitignore` file at the root of the repo. If it contains for example `x64`, it would ignore this file.

There would be two main possibilities then:

- edit this file to fit your need
- or force this file to be added; ie: `git add -f x64/SQLite.Interop.dll`

However, committing binary files is often [frowned upon](http://robinwinslow.co.uk/2013/06/11/dont-ever-commit-binary-files-to-git/). It's true in particular if you want to keep up to date with the latest package, hence if you plan to commit new versions of the dlls on a regular basis.

You might rather want to consider Nuget [package restore](https://docs.nuget.org/docs/reference/package-restore) feature. Basically the idea is that you commit a config file, and the client will automatically download the corresponding packages.

Comment: Bingo!  yep, .gitignore did in fact contain 'x64'. Especially ironic since I said 'Git ignored...' (doh)  I had found an example .gitginore which I edited and used but wasn't quite aware of what all was in there.  My Git education is enhanced, thanks.   And point well taken about the binaries, I agree package restore is a better idea, thank you.